# Putting groups on the same line in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I've built a report which is returning the correct data, but I was wondering if it were possible to group on the same line rather than on multiple lines.

An example will help!

The report currently outputs

```
User       Count    FinishingNextMonth    Finishing3Months    Finishing6Months
Jo Bloggs  5        Person A     
Jo Bloggs  5                              Person B
Jo Bloggs  5                                                  Person C
Jo Bloggs  5                                                  Person D
```

But I would much rather it outputted

```
User       Count    FinishingNextMonth    Finishing3Months    Finishing6Months
Jo Bloggs  5        Person A              Person B            Person C
Jo Bloggs  5                                                  Person D
```

Is this possible, and if so how?

Code as below:

```
declare @startdate datetime
declare @startdateplusone datetime
declare @startdateplusthree datetime
declare @startdateplussix datetime

set @startdate = '30 jul 2013'
set @startdateplusone = DATEADD(mm,1,@startdate)
set @startdateplusthree = DATEADD(mm,3,@startdate)
set @startdateplussix = DATEADD(mm,6,@startdate)

select 
u.username + ' ' + u.surname as Consultant, 
dbo.GET_CONTRACT_RUNNERS(u.UserId,@startdate) as Runners, 
(select fileas from objects where p.ApplicantId = ObjectID and p.EndDate > @startdate and p.EndDate <= @startdateplusone) as FinishingOneMonth,
(select fileas from objects where p.ApplicantId = ObjectID and p.EndDate > @startdateplusone and p.EndDate <= @startdateplusthree) as FinishingThreeMonths,
(select fileas from objects where p.ApplicantId = ObjectID and p.EndDate > @startdateplusthree and p.enddate <= @startdateplussix) as FinishingSixMonths
from placements p
inner join PlacementConsultants pc on pc.PlacementId = p.PlacementID
inner join Users u on u.UserId = pc.UserId
where p.StartDate < @startdate and p.EndDate > @startdate

group by u.UserName, u.Surname, EndDate, ApplicantId, u.userid
order by u.UserName, u.surname
```

Comment: What logic puts "Person C" on the "first" line and not "Person D"?

This is almost certainly something you should leave to your reporting application.

Comment: @gvee It's basically about dropping blank space more than anything.  It's going to be exported to Excel, so I'm happy to leave that as is and get rid of the blanks there, but prefer prettier data :D